# Chrome OS and OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, chrome-os

I'm using `ASUS Chromebook Flip` with `Google Chrome OS Version 59.0.3071.47 (Official Build) dev (32-bit)` and I would like to use my `OpenVPN` server.

My attempt(s):

- via `crosh` - I am able to connect to OpenVPN server via `openvpn` client (works as expected).
- via `OpenVPN Connect` (Android App) - `OpenVPN Connect` connects to OpenVPN server, yet not routing traffic.
- via `Chrome OS's native client` - I followed [OpenVPN on ChromeOS Documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/18TU22gueH5OKYHZVJ5nXuqHnk2GN6nDvfu2Hbrb4YLE/pub) (I imported `CA` and `client` certificates), yet while connecting I keep get prompted for `OTP`.

Please advise.